# Can I use a transistor as a switch to close a pin to GND?

Tags: arduino, transistors

I need to short an external pin to another external pin (gnd). [Link to Nikon D90 pinout.](http://pinoutsguide.com/DigitalCameras/nikon_d90_pinout.shtml)

I want to control this with an Arduino, can I use a transistor for this? (e.g. BC548)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it with a BC548 (or another NPN transistor). You need a circuit like the following one:

[image]

- At the input of the circuit (i/p) you have to connect the arduino
  output.
- At the output of the circuit (o/p) you have to connect the camera pin (SHUTTER or FOCUS).

To calculate Rc and Rb we need to check the Collector-Emitter Saturation Voltage in the [BC548 datasheet](http://www.philohome.com/sensors/gp2d12/gp2d12-datasheets/bc548.pdf). It is 0.25V for Ic = 10 mA, Ib = 0.5 mA. Low enough for your application. Then:

- Rc = (Vcc - Vce) / Ic = (5V-0.25V) / 0.01A = 475Ω --> 470Ω is the closest E24 value.
- Rb = (Vin - Vbe) / Ib = (5V-0.7V) / 0.0005A = 8.6kΩ --> This is the maximum value to have the transistor saturated, so I would pick a lower value to be on the safe side. I would recommend a resistor between 1kΩ to 4.7kΩ.

With this configuration, when you output HIGH from the arduino pin, you saturate the transistor and therefore the output goes LOW. So outputting HIGH from the arduino pin, you will trigger the FOCUS or SHUTTER signals.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps the OP much, as the camera presumably already has a pullup in place of Rc

Comment: I agree that the camera probably has a pullup already, but usually it is a much higher value (typically 10kΩ). So, considering I don't know for sure that the pullup exists and that it will probably be much higher, I would still use the Rc. If you really want to avoid using Rc, you can always test it without and if it works leave it without.

Comment: Thanks ferrangb, I'll try it this week and post my results.

Comment: @ferrangb: "I would recommend a 4.7kΩ resistor or lower."  Ten ohms is less than 4700 ohms; would that be OK?

Comment: @Passerby: What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry, that was snippier than intended

Comment: I agree with Passerby's edit. Rb should be between 1kΩ and 4.7kΩ. Rb limits the Ib current, so less than 1k would generate a higher than 5V/1k=5mA current, which is absolutely not needed for the transistor, can be dangerous for the Arduino, and wastes energy.